# How to create a collection like List<String,Object>?

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization, json.net

I need to create a list like `List<String,Object>` but I can't seem to do this.

I created a class:

```
public class Pair
{
    public String Key { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }
}
```

If I make a `List<Pair>`, my problem starts when I have to serialize it into JSON , I get something like:

```
{
    "Key": "version",
     "Value": "3.2.1"
},
{
    "Key": "name",
    "Value": "coordinateOperations"
}
```

While I am expecting:

```
{
    "version": "3.2.1"
},
{
    "name": "coordinateOperations"
}
```

My guess is I have to either find a way to have `List<String,Object>` or control the serialization mechanism. The latter looks tougher and seems more like a trick rather than a real solution.

Also, I **can't** have a `Dictionary<String,Object>` since I will have repeated keys. Maybe a lookup is more needed.

Comment: How do you serialize? I believe there has to be a possibility to hint the converter about the needed format.

Comment: i use JSON.Net to serialize .

Comment: After a quick look at the documentation, I found a way to customize the serialization of custom classes: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ContractResolver.html. There should be even simpler ways.

Comment: this looks really complicated !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why create your own? you can use `KeyValuePair`

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> nList = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>();
```

Comment: Just create a custom object with the above and override the .ToString() method.. I think that'll do the job.

Comment: I would go with this answer. You will have to create a custom serializer/deserializer convention for your desired JSON otherwise .Net won't know which property goes where as there will be no property named "version" or "name".

Comment: any hints as to how to start going about this ?

Comment: @ashutoshraina I have the same need for duplicated "key". Since this has the best answer, do you mind post your solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are unique, you could use what OWIN uses, which is `IDictionary<string, object>`

Comment: OP wrote "I can't have a Dictionary<String,Object> since I will have repeated keys.", so your solution does not work here.